# In shading mode, how to make material slot object face selection remain permanent

Tags: shaders, toon-shading

First post... hi everyone, newbie to Blender here.
In shading mode, I am using 2 material slots to apply different colors to a building. One material is assigned to building walls... the other to window faces. When I have all window faces selected and select the other material slot, I lose selection to windows faces and then have to manually reselect all faces again, time consuming. I wonder if there is a way to link selected window faces to assigned material slot for the selection to remain permanent. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean selecting faces that had a Material? if yes here is how :

[image]

If this faces isn't assigned to a Material you can save a selection by :

Ctrl + G > Assign to a New Group

[image]

You can assign-remove-select-deselect a Vertex Group in the object mesh tab

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot. Thanks Faris!

Comment: No problem brother